# non-module header in iOS FirebaseAnalytics Pod

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

After installing the Firebase/Messaging Pod on iOS I get the error:

```
Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'FirebaseAnalytics'
```

in `FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.h` on the line

```
#import <FirebaseCore/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.h>
```

What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same issue a few minutes ago. I was able to successfully resolve it by doing the following:

1. In your `Podfile`, uncomment the line that says `use_frameworks!`
2. Run `pod install`
3. In Xcode, do a Clean (⌘+K) and Build (⌘+B)

I hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't a great solution - it changes CocoaPods from using static libraries to dynamic frameworks. Depending how many Cocoapods you have, your app will startup a lot slower, especially on older iOS versions.

Comment: @JosephH The intention was to help unblock them, which this solution appears to have done. Since they provided no information about their project outside of the Firebase dependency, it didn't seem necessary to reason about each possible solution and their pros/cons/potential implications. I do think there is value in that information, though! If you have a solution that resolves this error without the increase to app startup I don't mind updating the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this and thanks to some help from the cocoapods team over the weekend, we determined it's an issue in firebase and will be solved in the next major release:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/973

There's also a workaround (a post install step in the Podfile) step mentioned there; to do this add a file containing this to your project as patch/FirebaseAnalytics.h:

```
// Workaround for https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/973
#import "FIRAnalytics+AppDelegate.h"
#import "FIRAnalytics.h"
#import "FIRAnalyticsSwiftNameSupport.h"
#import "FIREventNames.h"
#import "FIRParameterNames.h"
#import "FIRUserPropertyNames.h"
```

and add this to your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  # This post_install workaround should be removed when FirebaseAnalytics
  # removes its non-modular includes;
  # https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/973
  print "Fix up FirebaseAnalytics module ... \n"
  system 'cp patch/FirebaseAnalytics.h Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/Headers/'
end
```

As mentioned by @QMFNP you can also workaround it by adding `use_frameworks!` in your Podfile, but the downside of doing this is that it switches CocoaPods to one dynamic framework per pod and (if you have a lot of pods) your application startup time will get vastly longer, particularly on older versions of iOS.